# On OS X, can you force Chrome to open a new window on your current desktop rather than switch to the desktop that currently has Chrome opened?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

Say I have Desktop 1 (D1) and Desktop 2 (D2). I am currently focused on D2 and want to open a new Chrome window but there is already a window open in D1. I want to make it so that when I click the Chrome icon in the dock it opens a new window on the existing desktop rather than switching to the desktop with an open window. Is there a way to do this for all applications (new "instance" rather than switching focus to an existing one)?

Answer (score 4):

If you right click the Dock icon & select Options > None
then later, right-clicking the Dock icon & selecting New Window will open on the current Space.

[image]

I'm not certain how well that will work if you have "Displays have separate Spaces" enabled (& I'm not messing up my 6-Space, 2-Display layout to find out;) in System Prefs > Mission Control.

Comment: doesn't  work. it will still redirect me to another open chrome window

Comment: This is no longer applicable for newer macs....how do we do this in macOs high Sierra?